# Is there a draft mode for writing questions and answers?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, editing, answers

I would like to have a feature of saving a draft of a question and not just having to complete the question and send off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is part of the Stack Exchange mechanism for posting

> "Drafts are stored in redis for 7 days, with each site having storage
>   for one draft question and one draft answer per user."

for a clearer answer
[Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)

Answer (score 6):

One technique I use (frequently) is to copy the entire contents of a draft and paste it into a local text document.

If you want more capabilities than that, you can preview, save, and manage your drafts on the StackEdit site at https://stackedit.io/app# .

Comment: Looks like a useful site you shared, I appreciate that.